# Running multiple instances of a Python script concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a script that I run from the command line. I need to run many instances of the script concurrently to save time. Imagine each instance scrapes one Amazon product page that is passed to it as an argument in the command line and there are millions of these pages.

Right now, my core i7 CPU manages to run only 10-12 of these scripts without getting too hot (I have plenty of RAM and GPU left). Is there anything along the lines of multi-threading or parallel processing (I have just heard the names, btw) that can let me get more out of the CPU and save my time? As things stand now, it's going to take me a few straight months to complete the task... if my CPU survives.

Edit: each script opens a Chrome browser (selenium) navigates a webpage, scrapes some data (Beautiful Soup), and writes it to csv. But the script also spends a lot of time waiting/sleeping for web elements to become clickable/visible and for IP not to get banned.

Comment: Do these scripts do a lot of graphical work, i.e. opening browsers?

Comment: Have you tried running Chrome in headless mode?

Comment: Yes, that is what I do.

Comment: Wait—you’re asking how to parallelize this process even though you’re already running “10-12 of these scripts”?

Comment: will [this](https://gist.github.com/wooddar/df4c89f381fa20ce819e94782dc5bc04) be of help?

Comment: If you need sleep to not get IP banned, then you cannot increase the number of parallels on that site. That would be the same as reducing the sleep time, and you would get banned. Are you aware of this dilemma? I mean, are you accessing all the different sites?

Comment: @ken, right, but I can work around the IP issue. My problem is now the load on the CPU that doesn't let me run more instances of the script

Comment: @DavisHerring No, running numerous instances of the script is my current way of doing the work in parallel, whereby each instance scrapes a number of web pages. Since 10-12 concurrent instances seem to be the maximum my CPU can handle, I was asking if there is a more CPU-efficient way of achieving the same thing, like the multi-threading that is done from inside the code. My question is more of a design/approach question

Comment: Parallelization is not magic. Changing parallelization techniques will not reduce CPU load. At least not much. You need to reduce the load on individual scripts. I suggest you try [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). You will have to rewrite most of your scripts though.

Comment: If you're overheating the hardware to the point where taking off the covers and setting up a portable fan doesn't help, then maybe it's time to consider moving your application into the cloud.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes but my question is asking if there is a better way of doing this on my personal computer so that I won't overheat the hardware :)